# How to compare an image stored in the database with an input image from user using php and md5

Tags: php, mysql, image, md5

I want to compare an image with an image stored in the database.. is it possible to use md5 ? I mean will the file stored in the database has the same md5 value as the original file..?

```
//the input image
$image1 = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$image1 =addslashes(file_get_contents($image1));

//the stored image
$image2=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select image from 
civilregistry where nationalnumb=12345678900"));
$image2 = $image2[0];

$image1md5=md5(file_get_contents($image1));
$image2md5=md5(file_get_contents($image2));

if($image1md5==$image2md5)
{echo"compatible";}
else
{echo"not compatible";}
```

Note: I used addslashes before storing the image to the database.

Comment: Yeah, this should work. Have you tried running it? That's a good way to check lol

Comment: if I use:   $image1md5=md5(file_get_contents($image1));
it give me failed to open stream error .. and if i try it without file_get_contents the two md5 values never be compatible

Answer (score 0):

Don't use file_get_contents , Directly

```
$image1md5=MD5($image1);
$image2md5=MD5($image2);
```

and compare you may get the correct comparison.

NOTE : file_get_contents() function will read the content of a file you can see the below reference URL : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp